# GCC versions/flags and FAM

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, gnu-make, flexible-array-member

I'm trying to port our build system from `make` to `CMake`, and I encountered a problem that surprisingly not "Googleable"
Our code is C++ 11/14, compiles fine with GCC6.2, the `make` applies zillion switches when invoking GCC, mostly pedantic warnings. I built a `CMake` system that compiles (GCC 6.3) most of the code without a problem but some modules failed to build because of the following

> flexible array member ‘blahblah’ not at end of ‘struct‘

Aside why it appears in the C++ code. Why did it compile in the `make` based system? AFAIK, flexible array is not a part of C++ standard. GCC specific extension? What command line switch controls FAM behavior? How do I make it compile as it did in the original `make` system?

In case someone needs a snippet of compiled code

```
struct Foo
{
    int _10;
    double _20;
    int a[];
};

struct Bar
{
    Foo foo;
    double _1;
    int _2;
}
```

To add more context, the `cmake` file

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
>
> project(foo VERSION ${FOO_VERSION} DESCRIPTION "foo")
>
> set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
>
> set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD  99)
>
> add_executable(foo foo.cpp foo_backup.cpp main.cpp)
>
> set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
>
> target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/include ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/include/bar)

Comment: Surely, ff you are asking people what might differ between the build files to cause this, you need to post the build files...

Comment: Don't vary two things at once (your compiler and your build system). Get your cmake stuff to work with the "known good" compiler version, then change the compiler - or the other way around. Also, why don't you just copy the "zillion" flags?

Comment: Flexible array members appear in C99 - any chance that some of your files are compiled as C instead of C++ sources?

Comment: @Mat, zillion flags dispersed over 60kb of make file with quadrillion `if`s. so a) its quite complicated to figure out what is the final set of switches applied to the compilation b) I have a feeling that we dont need most of them, they are there mostly because of historical reasons

Comment: @underscore_d do you think it could be 6.2->6.3 difference?

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg: ... and yet your code no longer builds. Again, don't change both your build system and your compiler at the same time. Right now, you don't know what's to blame.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I saw this flag applied in our `make` -std=c99, but this is cpp file with actual cpp file, I think C compiler wouldnt compile CPP code, right?

Comment: I'd go with that your make file used a C compiler and CMake is using a C++ compiler - but who can say.  Why not try comparing the actual commands run?

Comment: @UKMonkey check my answer to Vroomfondel

Comment: You've not posted what commands are actually used - so it's not worth postulating if they'll compile it or not

Comment: @UKMonkey, before I will find how to retrieve actual parameters used on each compilation, in theory, what compiler should be able to accept FAM construct? C? C99? C++? Which one?

Comment: Compilers are only required to implement what is in the standard.  There's nothing saying that they're not allowed to add more.  This is where compiler extensions comes in, and "Undefined Behavour".  It's like asking which compilers can I not return a value in a function for ... ., not doing so is undefined, so some might error, some might warn, and others might open a black hole.

Comment: Would you deem it possible to rewrite your build to a "tabular" build config approach? Imagine a small scale relational database (or just a few tables) where you `select` the appropriate properties and elements instead of `if-else` chains? Would that make your build simpler/clearer without going to CMake?

Comment: @Vroomfondel I'm going to the CMake since it is more convenient build system, make is soooo seventies :)

Comment: In embedded environments CMake doesn't cut it either. Way to focused on "big" systems IMHO.

Comment: Have a look at [the answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48183371/triggering-c-source-define-frommake-command-line) to give you a feel what can be done with pure make in terms of build configuration. The question is if the new syntax of CMake or whatever is really so much simpler in the face of the cost of adding one more tool and level of indirection.

Comment: I think it begins to be "religious" issue, I believe in `make`, I dont believe in `make`, etc. From my point of view there is no reason to use make files directly in the year 2018. Go maintain `make` configurations for 10 distros of 4 OSes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make it compile as it did in the original make system

Revert to GCC 6.2. This `-pedantic` error was introduced for C++ in GCC 6.3.

See [compilation with 6.2](https://godbolt.org/g/aijZTC) and [compilation with 6.3](https://godbolt.org/g/iXw8Cr)

Disabling pedantic compilation will remove the error but entail other relaxations.

Comment: Yep, you are right, I've already found it using https://godbolt.org/ The 6.2 compiles my code, 6.3 and later will complain. I have a feeling we will have to fix it if we want to get modern compiler