# Triggering C source #define from`make` command line

Tags: makefile

I'd like to "link" a C source `#define` to a makefile variable - to be able to define or undefine via make.

For example,

```
// my C source file
#ifdef SOMETHING
   // do something
#else
   // do something else
#endif
```

Then `SOMETHING` would be triggered from the `make` command line:

`make something=true`

This works for my `makefile`:

```
ifeq ($(something),true)
    COMPILER_FLAGS += -DSOMETHING   
endif
```

I am wandering, is this the proper way?
Is there an easier or better solution?

Comment: Yes, that's a pretty common idiom for this kind of thing. Are you facing any particular problem with it ?

Comment: Thanks. Not having any problems. Just wanted to make sure this is the rigth way, since, after one #define, it seems I'll have to add a few more...

Comment: It is common but it has a rather unpleasant caveat: if you are debugging (or generating an automatic report e.g. for a software process checkpoint) then you somehow need to transport the defined macros from the transient command line to some stable storage form, that means logging the console output during the build process into some file that becomes part of the release. As it isn't a part of the sourcecode, even smart debuggers often can't figure out the define either. You'll have to decide if simple beats stable in your case.

Comment: Note that all the cool kids seem to be using higher level build systems such as CMake these days - I imagine this might make managing build variants a lot easier than ad hoc solutions operating directly on makefiles.

Answer (score 2):

The following is not an ad-hoc solution but it requires you to use a make library: [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) is the GNUmake table toolkit and was designed more or less with such a use case in mind. You can specify tables which you access with a (modest) form of the `select` statement known from a relational database. This way you escape convoluted `ifeq` hierarchies and can introduce build parameters rather easily. Of course one can argue that in my example three very simple `ifeq` paragraphs would have done also, without introducing a make library, but the advantage of the below solution is that tables force you to a separation of concerns and you don't need to worry that someone has sneaked in an addtional functionality in one of the `ifeq`'s aside from generating `#define`'s.

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

#define a 3-column table; there must be no empty cells (put in a comment)!
define project-defs =
3
type-1   APPLES   15
type-1   ORANGES  0
type-1   PEARS   /*empty*/

type-2   APPLES   0
type-2   ORANGES  15
type-2   PEARS   /*empty*/

type-3   APPLES   15
type-3   ORANGES  15
endef

#select column 2 and 3 of the above table and create a C-source line with '#define' from them
define project-defines :=
$(call map-select,2 3,$(project-defs),$$(call str-eq,$$1,$(project-type)),\#define $$1 $$2$$(newline))
endef

$(info Building with the following defines: $(project-defines))

$(file > project_def.h,$(project-defines))
```

With this makefile you now can invoke `make project-type=type-1` and so on and the makefile will generate for you `project_def.h` which will serve as a normal header file instead of invisible defines in the command line.